# Global loading namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a DLL that contains extension methods and I want to be able to use them in all my views without having to manually add the `@using MyLongNameSpaceHere` in each of my files.

Is there a way to globally load a namespace in all my Razor engine view?

Comment: @Igor Nop beacuse I want to get rid of the `@Using` call.

Comment: @KhairulIslam Nop beacuse the awser you point out is in c# file and I'm in a Razor view.

Comment: @Muffun - yes, see the 2nd answer in the list. It explicitly shows how to use the `web.config`. Answer by `Javad_Amiry`

Comment: @Igor Indeed. I had only check the accepted answer.

Comment: @KhairulIslam - that previous question is not what Muffun is asking though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the "***~/views/web.config***" file, use something as following:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```